# Unable to insert an image at "img src="

Tags: html, image, src

Something simple but frustrating. I cannot get the desired image.  I have tried drag and drop; single, double and triple click; Ctrl+Space.  I have brought my images into the Local Filesystem, I have tried:

```
Local Filesystem/Images/Site Plan.jpg
```

and

```
Site Plan.jpg
```

Comment: Can you please provide some sample code

Comment: Its not very clear what you are doing or asking. Are you trying to create an HTML page and your images aren't showing up? Are you using some authoring tool (I assume so by your drag and drop) and if so what one is it? What does your outputted HTML look like? Where is your image relative to where your HTML page is being hosted?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
Site%20Plan.jpg
```

(replace all spaces with %20)

Or just rename to `site_plan.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the space in the url is causing you problems.  Try: `Local Filesystem/Images/Site%20Plan.jpg`

Take a look at url encoding.